# Como colocar resetar un select solo con javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

Hola mi consulta es al seleccionar el segundo select si utilice el de filtrado, quiero que el primero de filtrar se coloque en la primera opcion y viceversa, solo utilizando `javascript` intente con el `document.getElementById.value` y no me resulto, quiero que se mantengan los valores pero que se coloque en la posision inicial

```html
<ul>
<li class="nav-item dropdown limargin">
        <select class="form-control" id="filterType">
           <option class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filtrar por tipo</option>
           <option>Dragon</option>
           <option>Electric</option>
           <option>Fighting</option>
           <option>Fire</option>
           <option>Flying</option>
           <option>Ghost</option>
           <option>Grass</option>
           <option>Ground</option>
           <option>Ice</option>
           <option>Normal</option>
           <option>Poison</option>
           <option>Psychic</option>
           <option>Rock</option>
           <option>Water</option>
        </select>
 </li>

 <li class="nav-item dropdown limargin">
      <select class="form-control" id="filterEggs">
         <option class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filtrar por huevos</option>
         <option>2 km</option>
         <option>5 km</option>
         <option>10 km</option>
         <option>Not in Eggs</option>
      </select>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
var filterType = document.getElementById('filterType');
var filterEggs = document.getElementById('filterEggs');
//controle el cambio de filterType
filterType.addEventListener("change", function(){
  //defino o selecciona la primera opcion del select
 filterEggs.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown limargin">

  <select class="form-control" id="filterType">

    <option class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filtrar por tipo</option>
    <option>Dragon</option>
    <option>Electric</option>
    <option>Fighting</option>
    <option>Fire</option>
    <option>Flying</option>
    <option>Ghost</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Ground</option>
    <option>Ice</option>
    <option>Normal</option>
    <option>Poison</option>
    <option>Psychic</option>
    <option>Rock</option>
    <option>Water</option>
  </select>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown limargin">

    <select class="form-control" id="filterEggs">
      <option class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filtrar por huevos</option>
      <option>2 km</option>
      <option>5 km</option>
      <option>10 km</option>
      <option>Not in Eggs</option>

    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Explicación:**

Lo que hago es primero obtener el select por su **ID**  mediante este controlo el cambio ó evento **change** al detectar un cambio establezco el selected mediante el index a la primera opcion es decir a la posición "0" , de la misma manera puedes hacerlo con el otro select.

Espero te sirva  suerte..!!

Comment: Mil Gracias me sirvio para cada evento en cada select saludos!!!